# Ubuntu 15.10 not detected by Samsung TV via displaport-HDMI

Tags: 15.10, hdmi, displayport

My HP EliteBook 840 does not have a HDMI port but a displayport, so I got an adapter to HDMI. I tried to connect to a Samsung TV (UE-50JU6870) via the adapter and a HDMI cable but it stays on black screen with "no signal".

I have tried with the open-source and the proprietary driver (fglrx) for my graphic card (Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8730M]).

I have a dual boot with windows 7, there the TV is detected.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked Displays (just type into dash to find it)? Might simply be you need to activate / enable it after hooking it up.

Comment: I have tried to find it there via the "Find Displays" button (dunno if it is really called like that in english but you get the picture) but it just shows the built-in display.

Comment: When you open Displays (settings) you would normally see a grayed out screen that is not activated. What happens if you have the tv on while booting? Does it show all the boot messages and everything? Ps. maybe there is a quick key on your keyboard. Something using FN + 5 or something to swap between displays.